# Parsing dl tag using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am trying to parse a `<dl>` tag using Jsoup. The `<dl>` tag contains `<dt>` tags and `<dd>` tags. I have a HashMap (`HashMap<String, List<String>`) in which I want to put the `<dt>`s as keys and `<dd>`s as values (there are multiple `<dd>` tags per `<dt>` tag.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<dl>
<dt>
    <span class="paramLabel">Parameters:</span>
</dt>
<dd>
    <code>y</code> - the ordinate coordinate
</dd>
<dd>
    <code>x</code> - the abscissa coordinate
</dd>
<dt>
    <span class="returnLabel">Returns:</span>
</dt>
<dd>
    the <i>theta</i> component of the point (<i>r</i>,&nbsp;<i>theta</i>) in polar coordinates that corresponds to the point (<i>x</i>,&nbsp;<i>y</i>) in Cartesian coordinates.
</dd>
```

I've tried the following:

```
String title = "";
List<String> descriptions = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
    Element child = children.get(i);

    if(child.tagName().equalsIgnoreCase("dt")) {
        if(descriptions.size() != 0) {
            block.fields.put(title, descriptions);
            descriptions.clear();

        }

        title = child.text();
    }
    else if(child.tagName().equalsIgnoreCase("dd")) {
        descriptions.add(child.text());

        if(i == children.size() - 1) {
            block.fields.put(title, descriptions);
        }
    }
}
```

I expected to get this:

```
 * Parameters -> y - the ordinate coordinate
 *               x - the abscissa coordinate
 * Returns    -> the theta component of the point (r, theta) in polar coordinates that corresponds to the point (x, y) in Cartesian coordinates.
```

But I got this:

```
 * Parameters -> the theta component of the point (r, theta) in polar coordinates that corresponds to the point (x, y) in Cartesian coordinates.


 * Returns    -> the theta component of the point (r, theta) in polar coordinates that corresponds to the point (x, y) in Cartesian coordinates.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to insert a **copy** of your descriptions list into the map, currently you manipulate 1 instance of the list. So instead of:

```
block.fields.put(title, descriptions);
```

create a new list, e.g.:

```
block.fields.put(title, new ArrayList<>(descriptions));
```